# "I will remain for you as..." or "I will remain to you as..."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Imagine some tourist trip is over and the members of the travelling group are to go back to their homes in different countries and they know that they will most likely not see each other anymore. Two members are saying their farewell words to each other. One of them is saying: "You will always remain **for** me as a very hilarious guy, and I will probably remain **for** you as the most boring person"

Is using "for" here correct or would "to" be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *to me* would be a more idiomatic choice here.

> You will always remain a very hilarious guy **to me**.

> **To me**, you will always remain a very hilarious guy.

You can use the definite article there.

> You will always remain **the love of my life**.

Similarly, we say

> Warmth and light brought joy **to my heart.**